# Error while updating the package castle core package to 4.4.1.0

Tags: nuget-package

After updating the castle core package i am facing the following exception .
i am using moq 4.13 .
assembly binding i mentioned as following. please help in resolving this issue.

bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.1.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"

Project  C:\mypath  on node 1 (DemoBuild target(s)).
RESTOREPACKAGES:
  " C:\mypath .nuget\NuGet.exe" update -self
  Checking for updates from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
 C:\mypath \build\build-git.config(118,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
 C:\mypath \build\build-git.config(118,5): error :   An error occurred while sending the request.
 C:\mypath \build\build-git.config(118,5): error :   Unable to connect to the remote server
 C:\mypath \build\build-git.config(118,5): error :   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 
 C:\mypath \build\build-git.config(118,5): error MSB3073: The command "" C:\mypath .nuget\NuGet.exe" update -self" exited with code 1.
Done Building Project " C:\mypath \build\build-git.config" (DemoBuild target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moq 4.13 has a dependency on Castle.Core >= 4.4.0. Do you need your own reference to 4.4.1 for any particular reason?

Otherwise I'm seeing connectivity issues so I would be looking at that first.

> error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
>
> error : An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> error : Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> error : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

NuGet.org [have recently removed TLS 1.0 and 1.1 support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/), not sure if that's a cause in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this and found out that nuget.org dropped support for TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on 15/06/2020. Now only TLS 1.2 can connect. If you use the -v verbosity 'detailed' option it tells you that it fails to make a secure SSL/TLS connection.